# Image scaling,make it it fit to bounds of UITableView cell with maintaining color combination and image quality in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

**Problem**:

I have used following code for scaling image and make it fit to bounds of UITableviewCell in monotouch.This code is scaling image but it is making image color faint means it is not maintaining color combination.So please provide any better solution.

**Code**:

public static UIImage Scale (UIImage source, SizeF newSize)
        {
            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext (newSize);
            var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext ();
            context.TranslateCTM (0, newSize.Height);
            context.ScaleCTM (1f, -1f);

```
        context.DrawImage (new RectangleF (0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height), source.CGImage);

        var scaledImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        return scaledImage;         
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want scale `UIImage`, then see [this method](http://www.fastchicken.co.nz/2011/03/28/scaling-and-rotating-an-image-in-monotouch/). It works fine. You should cache method's result in file system to avoid image scaling on every `GetCell`.

If you source images are the same or almost the same size like `UIImageView`s in `UITableViewCell` Mohib Sheth solution with setting `ContentMode` property is best. It source image have much greater size than `UIImageView`s in `UITableViewCell`, scrolling speed will be lower.

Comment: I also want to make it fit in bounds of UITableView cell.

Comment: You have access to `UITableVewCell`s `ContentView`. Put `UIImageView` into `ContentView` (`AddSubview()` method) and set it's frame according to `ContentView` frame.

Answer (score 0):

Read all about ContentMode for UIView in iOS [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/WindowsandViews/WindowsandViews.html)

For your requirement you would need to set the ContentMode property to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit

I cant help you with a sample code, since you haven't provided any code on how you are creating & populating the TableView.

Comment: I know about contentMode property I have use those but by using scaleAspectToFit it is not filling the cell completely.When I am using ScaleAspect fill and setting bounds property to true then Head part of image is cutting.So I cant use contentMode property.So is there any other solution?